# scanf-printf call messes non-ASCII chars after locale is set

Tags: c, windows, character-encoding, console-application, locale

I wonder why non-ASCII localed input-output fails:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
scanf("%s",buffer); // I type "příšerně"
printf("%s",buffer); // I get "pýˇçernŘ"
```

The locale is *Czech_Czech Republic.1250* and all the non-ASCII chars (říšě) are in CP1250. **Why it fails?** [The reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/) says

> In <cstdio> (<stdio.h>), formatted input/output operations are
>   affected by character transformation rules.

Using the default "C" locale gives correct output. **How to fix it?** On Windows I can't use UTF-8 in [setlocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/x99tb11d.aspx)

> If you provide a code page value of UTF-7 or UTF-8, setlocale will
>   fail, returning NULL.

In my project I use setlocale to read UTF8 text file and to display it on console using WinAPI MultiByteToWideChar function, but that requires system default locale, so I need to set the locale.

**edit**: I just found the input is in [CP852](http://www.acc.umu.se/~saasha/charsets/?charset=cp852&charset=cp1250), which is the default in "C". I suppose I could use [iconv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/libiconv/libiconv-1.14-2/), but I'd rather convince scanf not to stay with CP852.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of testing, I finaly got the working solution. It might not work for everybody since there is still a little mystery behind it. So this helped:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Czech_Czech Republic.852");
```

CP852 was the default console codepage for Central Europe since DOS times. There is also `chcp` DOS command and `SetConsoleCP` and `SetconsoleOutputCP` winAPI functions. For some reason, this still messes the output:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Czech_Czech Republic.1250");
SetConsoleCP(1250);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1250);
```

...but this is OK

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Czech_Czech Republic.852");
SetConsoleCP(852); // default in CE win console
SetConsoleOutputCP(852); // default in CE win console
```

Note that UTF-8 can't be set in `setlocale`, see the original question.